# Posting symbols with Facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to create special characters '•' (alt+7 with numlock on) on a Facebook api feed post using the PHP SDK. - Well, it doesn't work, there is an issue with the character's encoding. Also tried calling: `utf8_encode('•')` and that also didn't work.

When typing ' <3 ' Facebook parses it automatically and creates an heart sign (♥).

Any idea how should I encode that, or maybe there is a special magic charset like '<3' that creates a bullet?

Comment: do you have proper header and `<meta>` tags for utf8? <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html